# How to render an item based on a Boolean condition (in Angular v10)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method for finding a date in a list of dates

(Typescript)

```
checkForItem(date: string, historicalDates: string): boolean {
   if (historicalDates.includes(date)){
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I want to call it in my html in an `ngIf` condition

(HTML)

```
<ng-container *ngIf=checkForItem(element.date, element.historicalDates)>
   Confirmed
</ng-container>
```

I'm not sure if the syntax for the `ngIf` statement is correct. Basically, what is the syntax to check a condition; I want to call the `checkForItem` method and if it returns true, I want to show `'Confirmed'`

Comment: it seems to work imo, didn't you try it?

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: checkForItem(element.date, at the end of the expression [checkForItem(element.date,]

Comment: Could the missing '>' in </ng-container be the problem?

Comment: ngIf should be in quotes..  like this `*ngIf="checkForItem(element.date, element.historicalDates)"`

Comment: Would you please add the error to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `ngIf` with boolean expression or function that return boolean value: in both case you need to surround it by quotes `""`.

So if you want to use function try something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="checkForItem(element.date, element.historicalDates)">
   Confirmed
</ng-container>
```

Or you can define bool variable like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="IsShow">
   Confirmed
</ng-container>
```

And in your component:

```
checkForItem(date: string, historicalDates: string): void {
    if(historicalDates.includes(date)){
        this.IsShow = true;
    } else {
        this.IsShow = false;
    }
 }
```